# I want to update bios but not able to find bios update file in easy flash software of asus laptop

Tags: bios, ubuntu-18.04

I want to update bios but I not able to find bios update file in easy flash software of Asus laptop (x540LA). I am storing bios update file (X540LA-AS.303) on usb drive(fat32) and when i enter into EASY FLASH in boot menu, there is only 1 drive which is my usb drive and as I enter into it, I can only see folders but no bios update file.
I have installed Ubuntu on the system. Does for updating bios windows is required ?
Bios file download [link](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/X540LA/X540LAAS303.zip)

Comment: _"....there is only 1 drive which is my usb drive and as I enter into it, I can only see folders and **bios update file**."_ - If you can see the BIOS update file, what exactly is the issue? Your title and first sentence says you're not able to find the BIOS update file.

Comment: What file do you expect it to find? What file have you put on the drive? Please give the exact file name. It’s not showing up because it’s the wrong file. It is looking for a particular file type. Specify your laptop model.

Comment: My asus laptop series is X540LA and the bios update file name is "X540LA-AS.303"

Answer (score 0):

The file, after you unzip the archive, is indeed `X540LA-AS.303`.

Years ago I had a similar problem. The solution was to attach the right extension to the name. I don't remember the exact extension the utility expected; probably `.bin` or `.BIN` (case shouldn't matter on FAT32). Note "the right extension" in your case may be different.

Rename the file to `X540LA-AS.303.BIN` and retry. Or maybe even to `X540LA.BIN` to make it fit the 8.3 convention. It's a long shot but as I said I once encountered a utility that was picky about it.

Comment: I have tried with different names (X540LA-AS.303.BIN, X540LA.303, X540LA.BIN, .....) but nothing works. I have disabled secure boot option in boot menu. Can this be the problem.

Comment: @karan7777 Sorry to hear this. I hope another answer appears that will really help you. My answer remains for future reference as it *may* be helpful for somebody else, I think.

Comment: Check if there are OLDER bios update files, unpack(?) and compare filenames. This SHOULD IMO give clues to what the file extension/name should be. NOTE that e.g. *.exe or *.com might not be suitable for the updater.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with latest bios update (X540LA-AS.303) , it is not a binary file but update (X540LA-AS.301) is binary file . When I choose update (301), it is easily available in easy flash menu without any additional changes in bios file name.